# Groovy code to loop through GET requests and count nodes

Tags: groovy, soapui

Keen to hear feedback on how to make this A) less ugly B) adhere to atleast some basic coding principles! I'm using SOAPUI so any reference to properties means that something is getting stored in a test case property step.

I'd like to use a dictionary but am lost as to where I should start. I just know that the if statements below made for some very ugly and error prone code.

All advice, however critical is welcome. I'm keen to improve!

```
    import java.text.*
    import java.util.*

    def xmlSlurper = new groovy.util.XmlSlurper()  

    // Get the previous total for number of journals
    def journalCountProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def journalCountTotal = journalCountProp.getPropertyValue( "journalCount" )
    log.info " Previous JournalCount from last run: "+journalCountTotal

    def lastOffsetProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def lastOffsetHolder = lastOffsetProp.getPropertyValue( "offset" )
    log.info " Previous offset from last run: "+lastOffsetHolder

    // Get the response for a given timeline
    def response = xmlSlurper.parseText(context.expand('${GET Journal using Offset#Response}'));
    def currentJournalCount = response.Journals.Journal.size()
    log.info " Number of Journals in this Run: "+currentJournalCount

    //Getting the date from the last Journal (including an offset as the array count starts at 0)
    def lastDate = response.Journals.Journal[currentJournalCount-1].JournalDate
    log.info " Date from this response: "+lastDate

    //Add up the Journals total for a given date. 
    journalCountProp.setPropertyValue("journalQueryDate", String.valueOf(lastDate))

    def countJournalAsInt
    def offsetCountAsInt

    def accTypeBank = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeBankProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - BANK : "+accTypeBank
    def accTypeBankProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeBankTotal = accTypeBankProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeBankProp" )

    def accTypeCURRENT =  context.expand('${Properties#accTypeCURRENTProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - Current : "+accTypeCURRENT
    def accTypeCURRENTProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeCURRENTTotal = accTypeCURRENTProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeCURRENTProp" )

    def accTypeCURRLIAB = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeCURRLIABProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - CURRLIAB : "+accTypeCURRLIAB
    def accTypeCURRLIABProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeCURRLIABTotal = accTypeCURRLIABProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeCURRLIABProp" )

    def accTypeDEPRECIATN = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeCURRLIABProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - DEPRECIATN : "+accTypeDEPRECIATN
    def accTypeDEPRECIATNProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeDEPRECIATNTotal = accTypeDEPRECIATNProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeDEPRECIATNProp" )

    def accTypeDIRECTCOSTS = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeCURRLIABProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - DIRECTCOSTS : "+accTypeDIRECTCOSTS
    def accTypeDIRECTCOSTSProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeDIRECTCOSTSTotal = accTypeDIRECTCOSTSProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeDIRECTCOSTSProp" )

    def accTypeEQUITY = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeEQUITYProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - EQUITY : "+accTypeEQUITY
    def accTypeEQUITYProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeEQUITYTotal = accTypeEQUITYProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeEQUITYProp" )

    def accTypeEXPENSE = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeEXPENSEProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - EXPENSE : "+accTypeEXPENSE
    def accTypeEXPENSEProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeEXPENSETotal = accTypeEXPENSEProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeCURRLIABProp" )

    def accTypeFIXED = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeFIXEDProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - FIXED : "+accTypeFIXED
    def accTypeFIXEDProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeFIXEDTotal = accTypeFIXEDProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeFIXEDProp" )

    def accTypeLIABILITY = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeLIABILITYProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - LIABILITY : "+accTypeLIABILITY
    def accTypeLIABILITYProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeLIABILITYTotal = accTypeLIABILITYProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeLIABILITYProp" )

    def accTypeOTHERINCOME = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeOTHERINCOMEProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - OTHERINCOME : "+accTypeOTHERINCOME
    def accTypeOTHERINCOMEProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeOTHERINCOMETotal = accTypeOTHERINCOMEProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeOTHERINCOMEProp" )

    def accTypeOVERHEADS = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeOVERHEADSProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - OVERHEADS : "+accTypeOVERHEADS
    def accTypeOVERHEADSProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeOVERHEADSTotal = accTypeOVERHEADSProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeOVERHEADSProp" )

    def accTypeREVENUE = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeREVENUEProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - REVENUE : "+accTypeREVENUE
    def accTypeREVENUEProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeREVENUETotal = accTypeREVENUEProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeREVENUEProp" )

    def accTypeSALES = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeSALESProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - SALES : "+accTypeSALES
    def accTypeSALESProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeSALESTotal = accTypeSALESProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeSALESProp" )

    def accTypeTERMLIAB = context.expand('${Properties#accTypeTERMLIABProp}').toInteger()
    //log.info "AccountType - TERMLIAB : "+accTypeTERMLIAB
    def accTypeTERMLIABProp = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def accTypeTERMLIABTotal = accTypeTERMLIABProp.getPropertyValue( "accTypeTERMLIABProp" )

    def journalLineItems = response.Journals.Journal.JournalLines

    if( currentJournalCount < 100)
       {
        log.info " Nothing to see here - looks like we've reached the end of the journals"
        //add existing total to current response total
        log.info " JournalCount: "+(journalCountTotal.toInteger() + currentJournalCount.toInteger())
        offsetCountAsInt =journalCountTotal.toInteger() + currentJournalCount.toInteger()
        journalCountProp.setPropertyValue("journalCount",String.valueOf(offsetCountAsInt))


        for (lineItem in journalLineItems.JournalLine)
        {
            log.info "NOTE: From <100 Loop: "+lineItem.AccountType
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'BANK')
            {           
                accTypeBank++
                accTypeBankProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeBankProp",String.valueOf(accTypeBank))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'CURRENT')
            {   
                accTypeCURRENT++    
                accTypeCURRENTProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeCURRENTProp",String.valueOf(accTypeCURRENT))        
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'CURRLIAB')
            {   accTypeCURRLIAB++
                accTypeCURRLIABProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeCURRLIABProp",String.valueOf(accTypeCURRENT))  
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'DEPRECIATN')
            {           
                accTypeDEPRECIATN++
                accTypeDEPRECIATNProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeDEPRECIATNProp",String.valueOf(accTypeDEPRECIATN))   
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'DIRECTCOSTS')
            {           
                accTypeDIRECTCOSTS++
                accTypeDEPRECIATNProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeDIRECTCOSTSProp",String.valueOf(accTypeDIRECTCOSTS)) 
            }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'EQUITY')
            {           
                accTypeEQUITY++
                accTypeEQUITYProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeEQUITYProp",String.valueOf(accTypeEQUITY))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'EXPENSE')
            {           
                accTypeEXPENSE++
                accTypeEXPENSEProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeEXPENSEProp",String.valueOf(accTypeEXPENSE))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'FIXED')
            {           
                accTypeFIXED++
                accTypeFIXEDProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeFIXEDProp",String.valueOf(accTypeFIXED))
            }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'LIABILITY')
            {           
                accTypeLIABILITY++
                accTypeLIABILITYProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeLIABILITYProp",String.valueOf(accTypeLIABILITY))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'OTHERINCOME')
            {           
                accTypeOTHERINCOME++
                accTypeOTHERINCOMEProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeOTHERINCOMEProp",String.valueOf(accTypeOTHERINCOME))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'OVERHEADS')
            {           
                accTypeOVERHEADS++
                accTypeOVERHEADSProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeOVERHEADSProp",String.valueOf(accTypeOVERHEADS))
            }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'REVENUE')
            {           
                accTypeREVENUE++
                accTypeREVENUEProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeREVENUEProp",String.valueOf(accTypeREVENUE))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'SALES')
            {   
                accTypeSALES++
                accTypeSALESProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeSALESProp",String.valueOf(accTypeSALES))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'TERMLIAB')
            {           
                accTypeTERMLIAB++
                accTypeTERMLIABProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeTERMLIABProp",String.valueOf(accTypeTERMLIAB))
                }

        }

       }
    else
       {
        countJournalAsInt = journalCountTotal.toInteger() + currentJournalCount.toInteger()
        journalCountProp.setPropertyValue("journalCount", String.valueOf(countJournalAsInt))

        log.info "last offset "+lastOffsetHolder
        offsetCountAsInt = lastOffsetHolder.toInteger()+100

        journalCountProp.setPropertyValue("offset",String.valueOf(offsetCountAsInt))

        for (lineItem in journalLineItems.JournalLine) 
        {
            log.info "NOTE: From main loop: "+lineItem.AccountType
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'BANK')
            {           
                accTypeBank++
                accTypeBankProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeBankProp",String.valueOf(accTypeBank))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'CURRENT')
            {   
                accTypeCURRENT++    
                accTypeCURRENTProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeCURRENTProp",String.valueOf(accTypeCURRENT))        
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'CURRLIAB')
            {   accTypeCURRLIAB++
                accTypeCURRLIABProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeCURRLIABProp",String.valueOf(accTypeCURRENT))  
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'DEPRECIATN')
            {           
                accTypeDEPRECIATN++
                accTypeDEPRECIATNProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeDEPRECIATNProp",String.valueOf(accTypeDEPRECIATN))   
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'DIRECTCOSTS')
            {           
                accTypeDIRECTCOSTS++
                accTypeDEPRECIATNProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeDIRECTCOSTSProp",String.valueOf(accTypeDIRECTCOSTS)) 
            }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'EQUITY')
            {           
                accTypeEQUITY++
                accTypeEQUITYProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeEQUITYProp",String.valueOf(accTypeEQUITY))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'EXPENSE')
            {           
                accTypeEXPENSE++
                accTypeEXPENSEProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeEXPENSEProp",String.valueOf(accTypeEXPENSE))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'FIXED')
            {           
                accTypeFIXED++
                accTypeFIXEDProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeFIXEDProp",String.valueOf(accTypeFIXED))
            }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'LIABILITY')
            {           
                accTypeLIABILITY++
                accTypeLIABILITYProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeLIABILITYProp",String.valueOf(accTypeLIABILITY))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'OTHERINCOME')
            {           
                accTypeOTHERINCOME++
                accTypeOTHERINCOMEProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeOTHERINCOMEProp",String.valueOf(accTypeOTHERINCOME))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'OVERHEADS')
            {           
                accTypeOVERHEADS++
                accTypeOVERHEADSProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeOVERHEADSProp",String.valueOf(accTypeOVERHEADS))
            }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'REVENUE')
            {           
                accTypeREVENUE++
                accTypeREVENUEProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeREVENUEProp",String.valueOf(accTypeREVENUE))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'SALES')
            {   
                accTypeSALES++
                accTypeSALESProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeSALESProp",String.valueOf(accTypeSALES))
                }
            if (lineItem.AccountType == 'TERMLIAB')
            {           
                accTypeTERMLIAB++
                accTypeTERMLIABProp.setPropertyValue("accTypeTERMLIABProp",String.valueOf(accTypeTERMLIAB))
                }


        }


        testRunner.gotoStepByName("GET Journal using Offset")
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

One improvement could be to do:

```
def testRunnerMap = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties").with {
  // Add all properties you want to get from the testRuner to this array
  [ 'journalCount', 'offset', 'accTypeBankProp', 'accTypeCURRENTProp' ].collectEntries { prop ->
    [ "$prop":getPropertyValue( prop ) ]
  }
}
```